# Signing up users who have not registered

Tags: design, api-design, web-api

I am building an app where you can invite your friends to join the platform and discuss various topics. (almost Reddit).

**Functionality:** When you create a topic you can enter the email of users you want to add. If some of the users are not registered with the platform, we send them an email, asking to get onboarded and see what discussion is happening on the topic.

**Implementation:** Create an entry in `topic` table. For user's being added, check if they exist in `user` table.

If yes, then create entry in `user_topic` table.

If no, then add to `user` table, send an invite to join and created entry in `user_topic`.

**Confusion:** Should the user be added to the `user` table, even though he has not been onboarded to the platform? And when he signs up, we patch in all the details we ask for. Is this the right approach?

**Solutions?:**

1. Add users to the table. When the user signs up, we `POST` a new user, but we patch in the details in the backend. This allows the user to be able to see everything that happened on the topic when he signs up. **Issues:** We have created an entry for a user even though he is not signed up. You could end up signing up for users who are unwilling.
2. We create a separate table where we keep track of the topics an unregistered email has signed up. When a new user is being created we check both the `user` and `unregistered_user` table and add the user. We do not create a `user` entry until he signs up. **Issues:** We have to check two tables when doing any operation. Every reply made to the topic will have to use the two tables.

**Question:**
How do you do it in your application? I am willing to change the approach as well. What is the recommended approach? (not sure if there is one. )

Comment: You probably should not store anything about the invitee because that person hasn’t given you permission to store any kind of data about them. That’s both an ethical and a legal question. Especially in regions with strict privacy laws (like the EU) storing anything about non-users might very well be outright illegal.

Answer (score 3):

I have worked on systems where the majority of the rows on the Users table where "ghost users" invited to join the system. This was very confusing, and often presented real problems when it came to business scenarios that needed to separate "real" users from "ghost" users.

Your proposed system will send invitations so instead of an `unregistered_users` table, I would prefer to have `invitations` table, which will track things like:

- When the invitation was sent
- The user that generated the invitation
- Token associated with the invitation

I would have a special page for users responding to the invitation that included the invitation token, so we only need to check in the `invitations` table. As the the on-boarding process is completed, the user can be created as normal and the invitation marked as complete.

As a bonus, this will give a very clear way to measure conversions.

Answer (score 1):

In your second approach, the `unregistered_users` table can also fill up with users who are unwilling to complete the sign-up process, so you get a serious disadvantage (reference two tables, where records can move from one to the other) without any real advantage.

Instead, I would keep track in the `users` table when the invite was sent and when the sign-up was completed. Then you can periodically purge the user records that have not signed up within X days/weeks of being invited.